# Why can I only split panes to the left using my leader key?

Tags: vim

Here are the vim commands/configs I'm working with:

```
noremap ' <NOP>
let mapleader = "'"

noremap <leader>cc :leftabove new<CR>
noremap <leader>hh :leftabove vnew<CR>
noremap <leader>tt :rightbelow new<CR>
noremap <leader>nn :rightbelow vnew<CR>
```

For key choices / positional context: I'm using dvorak, so the apostrophe is the equivalent of qwerty "q", and chtn is equivalent of ijkl

What I'm experiencing is that when I do `<leader>hh`, I correctly get a new pane to the left. But, none of the other commands work.

Any ideas why?

#### Update

So, I've found that these work:

```
" Pane Creating
nmap <leader><A-c> :leftabove new<CR>
nmap <leader><A-h> :leftabove vnew<CR>
nmap <leader><A-t> :rightbelow new<CR>
nmap <leader><A-n> :rightbelow vnew<CR>
```

But I don't know why.
As far as I know, I don't have any `<leader>` chtn mappings

Update
output of `:verbos map <leader>`
[image]

Comment: What do you get instead of the desired result?

Comment: for example, when I do <leader>nn, my cursor just goes to the right 2 characters (n is my move right key)

Comment: Try `nmap` instead of `noremap`.

Comment: same behavior. It seems for up/left/down the cursor just moves instead of being bound/picked-up-by the leader key

Comment: Try `:verbos map <leader>` and see if something is not overriding your mappings.

Comment: added a picture to my question. It doesn't look like anything would be overridding the n, t, or c directions. Here is my full keymap though: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/dotfiles/blob/master/home/.vim/vimrc/keymap.vim

Comment: For those passing by, this is solved. I don't remember what the solution was, but here is my vimrc: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/dotfiles/blob/master/home/.config/nvim/keymap.vim